# How to edit the format of 'Part#' on the product page in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I researched and found that I can find the 'part#' in view.phtml in app/design/frontend/default/mencom/template/catalog/product. The most relevant row I could find is

```
<div class="product-parts">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('SKU');?></span><?php echo $_product->getSku();?></div>
```

But it doesn't say anything about 'Part#' in the code.[image: click here to view the screenshot]

All I want is to add a space between 'Part#' and SKU(T35-...)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Share ur url you want to add space after Part#

Comment: Here it is. 
https://www.mencom.com/shop/ethernet-m12-d-coded-rj45/ethernet-braid-shielded-continuous-flex-cordset-2-pairs-rj45-male-rj45-male-straight-5m-24awg-1-5a-tpe.html

Comment: You want a space after Part# right

Comment: Yes, I want to add a space after Part# but can't find where to edit.

Comment: Add your css file .product-view .product-shop .product-parts span {
  padding-right: 3%;
}

Comment: Search for the term "Part #" in code or in Database, this must be some where in the system.

Comment: There should be but I'd like to know where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `css` file

```
mencom/css/styles0.css

.product-view .product-shop .product-parts span {
    padding-right: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below

```
<div class="product-parts">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('SKU');?></span> <?php echo $_product->getSku();?></div>
```

or as below

```
<div class="product-parts">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('SKU');?></span><?php echo ' ' . $_product->getSku();?></div>
```

I guess you have translated `SKU` to `Part #` using translation.
File : `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv`

Comment: Neither of them works...

Comment: I think so but where can I the translated SKU to edit?

Comment: File : app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv

Comment: No, not in there...